# How do I update the certificate used for backend authentication in my AWS elastic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

How do I update the certificate used for backend authentication in my AWS elastic load balancer?

I can't find anything in the AWS console or docs that explains how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not a way to update the backend authentication via the management console, but you can use the command line interface to do this.

The process is documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-backend-auth.html, in the "Using the Command Line Interface" section.

The link above has the necessary details, but conceptually the steps are:

1. Obtain your backend server's public key.
2. Use `elb-create-lb-policy` to create a new `PublicKeyPolicyType` policy for that public key.
3. Use `elb-create-lb-policy` to create a new `BackendServerAuthenticationPolicyType` based on the new public key policy you just created. (You can also include previously existing public key policies if your load balancer has instances that still have old certificates; simply add more `--attribute` arguments for those public key policies. You can see existing policies for the load balancer with the `elb-describe-lb-policies` command.)
4. Use `elb-set-lb-policy` to tell your load balancer to use your new backend server authentication policy for the desired port.

Comment: I found this link to be more useful than the one referenced above: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure_backendauth_clt.html